# .xcodeproj doesn't open in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Until this evening everything was fine. But now Xcode doesn't open .xcodeproj files.
When I start Xcode then click File->Open and then click on .xcodeproj file, the open dialog is showing me .xcodeproj file's contents instead of opening the project. I found on the web that it may be due to an old version of Xcode but I am using 3.2.4.

Comment: `Until that evening everything was fine` :)

Comment: Try this.  In XCode, view menu, select "Show Toolbar".  What might be happening is that XCode is hiding the toolbar and Project Explorer which makes it look like the project isn't open and all you see is the contents of the xcodeproj file.

Answer (score 0):

What format is the volume on which the projects reside ? An Xcode project is actually a bundle, that is a directory containing a project.pbxproj file (this is the only important file) and some user-specific settings files (which are not important). Make sure the project.pbxproj file is present and has appropriate permissions. Also if this is a non HFS+ volumes then that may be part of the problem.

Comment: Mac OS Extended. Yes, *.pbxproj files are present in every project. Prior to this evening all the projects opened normally. Now I can only work with "Recent projects".

Comment: What about permissions ? (Both on the .xcodeproj directory and on the .pbxproj file.) Also try creating a new project and see if that opens.

Comment: I can create new project and work with it. But open it I can just using the shortcut in the "Recent projects".

Answer (score 0):

I got same error in my project finally i founded my answer. there total two option for  solve this issue.

1. There is need one backup of your project. you can replace your .xcodeproj  with old file.
2. you have to create new project and than  have to add  All old  project file   in new project.